# Why is my video that worked fine previously glitching now?

Tags: mp4, video-player

Recently I revisited my old kickstarter project, just to find that the video produced heavy glitches, as shown in the picture below. These were (and are) not there in the original .mp4, and only appeared way after the [project](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/1534474899/the-flexatube-a-mathematical-folding-puzzle?lang=de) was finished. I assume the video player of kickstarter implemented some backwards-incompatible changes or bugs, or could it be my browser Frontend? Do you see them as well? I use Firefox in the newest version.
Would be great if someone here has insight on this.

[image: video glitch]